# Trying to Increment a variable on its inheritance python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, subclass

Hi there am new to OOP and python, I am currently trying to increment a User Id variable from a child Class, when I create an instance of the parent class using inheritance it doesn't seem to recognise the Id Variable from its parent class. Example here

```
class User:
    _ID = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.id = self._ID
        self.__class__._ID += 1

class Customer(User):
    def __init__(self, name):

    def lastname(self):

       return "self.name.split()[-1]"
```

If i do i am able to access the class attribute

```
>> Chris = User("Christopher Allan")
>> Chris.id
>> 0
```

When I try to run

```
>> Andy = Customer('Andy Smith')
>> Andy.id 

>>  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#83>", line 1, in <module>
    Andy.id
    AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'id'
```

**Update**

I completed the rest of the Customer Class which was the cause of the code not working for me, sorry about that people I used pass before as for briefness of question I didn't test that it would work with pass in the Customer class.

Comment: can't reproduce, seems to work fine for me.  What version of python?

Comment: Instead of `self.__class__._ID += 1` I would use `User._ID += 1`.

Comment: So you're definitely not overriding `__init__` in the `Customer` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Customer` does not have the `id` attribute as the base class (`User`) never has its `__init__` method called, and you are not otherwise defining it. Since you are overriding the base class' `__init__` method you also need to call `super` so that the inherited code is also called:

```
class Customer(User):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Customer, self).__init__(name)
```

Comment: Thanks for that nice explaination.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if your `__init__` method doesn't actually *do* anything (other than calling `super().__init__`, you might as well not have it at all. If you don't override the method, the inherited version will be called instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me in both [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) and [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7). Instead, i'd suggest that the error lies in your indentation error on line 3.

**[python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7)**

```
>>> class User:
...         _ID = 0
...         def __init__(self, name):
...                 self.name = name
...                 self.id = self._ID; self.__class__._ID += 1
... 
>>> class Customer(User):
...       pass
... 
>>> Andy = Customer('Andy Smith')
>>> Andy.id
0
>>> import sys
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
>>>
```

---

**[python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x)**

```
>>> class User:
...         _ID = 0
...         def __init__(self, name):
...                 self.name = name
...                 self.id = self._ID; self.__class__._ID += 1
... 
>>> class Customer(User):
...       pass
... 
>>> Andy = Customer('Andy Smith')
>>> Andy.id
0
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.4.0b2 (v3.4.0b2:ba32913eb13e, Jan  5 2014, 11:02:52) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
>>>
```

Comment: My Mistake that code does work, i just tested it now, in the code that was not working for me I had a class method in the Customer Class, and that was the reason it was not working for me, as I was not including     def __init__(self, name):
       super(Customer, self).__init__(name) , thanks for your trying to help me out none the less.